# Membership payments missing from contact's contribution screen

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, contacts

**Solution found:**
*The Member Dues financial type was missing a designated Income financial account. It must have gone away during an upgrade. Adding it back in fixed this issue.*

[image]

---

Membership transactions have disappeared from the Contributions screen in Contact records. The top of this screenshot indicates the contact has 12 contributions, but only 7 are displayed. There are no next/previous links.

The missing contributions are all membership transactions. Any reason why these would stop showing up? Any way to restore them?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is Civi 4.6.9 on WP 4.3.1

Here is an example of a search for all contributions and all contribution types from another member. Notice the summary says there are 9 results, but it only displays 4 transactions....

[image]

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot of the Membership tab, and the 'edit' of the membership where you should get to see related payments. Also can you query the database for civicrm_contributions belonging to that contact_id

Comment: Here are the screenshots. The related payments are not showing up. This person has been a member since 2011 and has renewed each year. What would the query syntax be for your suggestion?

Comment: Has anyone deleted any Financial Types? Query would probably be SELECT * from civicrm_contribution WHERE `contact_id` = xx

Comment: Thanks for the query. It returns all twelve all transactions as expected. All financial types in the results correspond with the available types. None have been deleted. I have tested several contacts and Civi screens. Member dues transactions are missing across the board. The data is there, but Civi isn't displaying it.

Comment: I found the solution and noted at the top of this post. thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad you found it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer by Eric as an answer so it can be 'accepted' and hence have this question 'answered'

The Member Dues financial type was missing a designated Income financial account. It must have gone away during an upgrade. Adding it back in fixed this issue